# How to get next row column by javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Below the structure where i have problem

```
<tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>
        <button onclick=someFunc() class='btn'>DoSomething</button>
    </tr>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan='3' style = "height: 400px; width: 500px">
        <div id='container'></div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

And here i can't get access to column with id colspan ='3' and div with id 'container' when button pressed.
I know its very noob question, but i'm new in javasript and can't find specific question with good explanation.

Here I'm trying to get access to my div

```
$(".btn").click(function(){
    $(this).parent('tr').next('td').hide();
});
```

**EDIT**

Its table of some information order. And when button clicked accordingly div must hide or show graph. Graph will be in div with class = "container". So my thought is to show some statistic information, and if user want to show graph i show him it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> And when button clicked accordingly div must hide or show graph.

Try substituting [.toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle) for [.hide()](http://api.jquery.com/hide)

---

> Yes, I can make like this. But i have hundreds block of codes like
>   above. And accordingly hundreds divs with id "container". I want
>   special make special function that hides  only in block where
>   button i pressed.

Try changing `id=container` to `class=container` , then select `container` to `toggle` utilizing [.index()](http://api.jquery.com/index)

---

```js
    $(".btn").on("click", function(e) {
        // substituted `.toggle()` for `.hide()`
        $(".container").eq($(this).index(".btn")).parent().toggle();
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<table>
  <tbody>
<tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>
        <button class='btn'>DoSomething</button>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan='3' style = "height: 400px; width: 500px">
        <div class='container'>a</div>
    </td>
</tr>
    <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>
        <button class='btn'>DoSomething</button>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan='3' style = "height: 400px; width: 500px">
        <div class='container'>b</div>
    </td>
</tr>
    <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>
        <button class='btn'>DoSomething</button>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan='3' style = "height: 400px; width: 500px">
        <div class='container'>c</div>
    </td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Your code will hide all rows with `colspan=3` not just the next one after the button.

Comment: Yes, I can make like this. But i have hundreds block of codes like above. And accordingly hundreds divs with id "container". I want special make special function that hides <td> only in block where button i pressed.

Comment: @ШыназАлиш `id`'s, should be singular, unique, for valid `html` ?

Comment: @ШыназАлиш If you have multiple container DIVs, it should be `class="container"` not `id="container"`.

Comment: @guest271314 can i make it simple than your updated answer? I saw it, and it hard to understand for me, i noob in javascript.

Comment: @guest271314 I understand your thought, very good idea, its what i want. But i don't understand your answer.  Where should i write this functions, where you give you for your parameter numbers(I mean "i" and "el"), I new in javascript. But in general, i understand your idea, and i will solve my project with your solution.

Comment: `i` is `index` of element within collection of elements. For example an `array` having three items `["a", "b", "c"]` would return `index` `0` : "a", `index` `1`: "b", `index` `2` : "c" . `el` is the `element`; for example `el.className` for `btn` element would return `string` "btn" . Adding `index` to `btn` element _and_ corresponding `container` element should match `btn-0` with `container-0` element. See http://api.jquery.com/each _".each( function )
function
Type: Function( Integer index, Element element )
A function to execute for each matched element."_

Comment: @ШыназАлиш _"Where should i write this functions"_ . Place `.each()` calls _before_ `click` function.

Comment: @ШыназАлиш fwiw, `js` could probably be shortened further by utilizing `.index()` within `click` function to select corresponding `container` `class`

Comment: @guest271314, i unerstand you, you explaining very good, thanks for it for your. But in example above it working or by click of button. Can it work automatically?

Comment: See at original post `$(".btn").click(function(){` ? Can describe "automatically" ? "toggle" http://api.jquery.com/toggle `container` `class` on `click` , between `visible` , `hidden` ?  What is expected result ?

Comment: @guest271314, under word "automatically" i mean could we make it for example when page is loading? As i understand, we give unique class by pressing button. And how i can request them? My proejct screen is [link]http://imgur.com/lXs9grU. Here i loading graph information with ajax. So i load, and show graph to accordingly column,of accordingly statistic. So your idea is very good for me.

Comment: Toggle is veryyyyyyyyyyyy useful for me)). another one thanks for your)

Answer (score 1):

The button's parent is `td` not `tr` you need to use [closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest) to find the `tr` containing the button, then use [.next()](http://api.jquery.com/next) to get the next `tr` element and [.find('td')](http://api.jquery.com/find) to find the `td` inside it

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $(".btn").click(function() {
    $(this).closest('tr').next().find('td').hide();
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>
      <button onclick=someFunc() class='btn'>DoSomething</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan='3' style="height: 400px; width: 500px">
      <div id='container'>soemthing</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I want to hide this <td colspan='3' style = "height: 400px; width: 500px"> when button pressed. I write your code in my project, but nothing happened((

Comment: In the given markup you have a issue.. instead of `</td>` you have used `</tr`

Comment: @ШыназАлиш can you try to recreate the issue using http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/qsxd9q0x/1/ and share the updated code

Comment: @ШыназАлиш We're not psychic, we can't tell what you're doing differently unless you post the code.

Comment: I have hundred blocks like above code block. Also i have hundred button with this class. I paste your code, run, and pressed the button, nothing happened.  Also i added this link [link]<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(this).parents('tr').next('tr').hide()
```

this might work

Answer (score 0):

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>
      <button onclick='someFunc(this)' class='btn'>DoSomething</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan='3' style="height: 400px; width: 500px">
      <div id='container'>soemthing</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>


<script>
function someFunc(BTN){         
        $(BTN).closest('tr').next('tr').find('td').hide();
    }
</script>
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/r8xwff3u/)